# How would I say "What does X mean?" in mandarin?

Tags: translation

This would be useful to know if learners encounter a word they're unaware of (such as a slang/jargon word) that an outsider wouldn't know possibly off the bat.

Comment: A side question, is *off of the bat* a acceptable variation of *off the bat*? Thanks!

Comment: Dan I don't think so. I've only heard and used "off the bat" e.g. "right off the bat, I forgot his name"

Answer (score 7):

you say should say this

“X 是什么意思？”

Comment: Or “*X 的意思是什么？*”

Comment: This is just what the native speakers from China uses when I was talking to them. There are different dialects of mandarin so they might also use that also.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to say this is:

> 什么叫做X？

I used to hear this from curious little kids all the time.